# PHP fetch data is slow

Tags: php, postgresql, performance, pdo, foreach

I have a php file with many sql statements (postgres - db) the queries take around 1 second to be executed. But I think fetching the data takes too long. Is there a way to make this part faster:

```
<?php

// Call this at each point of interest, passing a descriptive string
function prof_flag($str)
{
    global $prof_timing, $prof_names;
    $prof_timing[] = microtime(true);
    $prof_names[] = $str;
}

// Call this when you're done and want to see the results
function prof_print()
{
    global $prof_timing, $prof_names;
    $size = count($prof_timing);
    for($i=0;$i<$size - 1; $i++)
    {
        echo "<b>{$prof_names[$i]}</b><br>";
        echo sprintf("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;%f<br>", $prof_timing[$i+1]-$prof_timing[$i]);
    }
    echo "<b>{$prof_names[$size-1]}</b><br>";
}

prof_flag("Start");
$time_start = microtime(true);


prof_flag("Connect to DB");

require("php/00connection.php");


prof_flag("Perform query");

$stmt_dbstorage_helium = $conn->query("SELECT used_space, epoch_time FROM db_storage WHERE host_id = 1 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_dbstorage_neon = $conn->query("SELECT used_space, epoch_time FROM db_storage WHERE host_id = 2 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_dbstorage_argon = $conn->query("SELECT used_space, epoch_time FROM db_storage WHERE host_id = 3 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_dbstorage_krypton = $conn->query("SELECT used_space, epoch_time FROM db_storage WHERE host_id = 4 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();

$stmt_available_tickets_helium =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets_available WHERE host_id=1 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_available_tickets_neon =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets_available WHERE host_id=2 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_available_tickets_argon =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets_available WHERE host_id=3 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_available_tickets_krypton =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets_available WHERE host_id=4 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();

$stmt_connections_helium = $conn->query("SELECT connections, epoch_time FROM connections WHERE host_id = 1 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_connections_neon = $conn->query("SELECT connections, epoch_time FROM connections WHERE host_id = 2 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_connections_argon = $conn->query("SELECT connections, epoch_time FROM connections WHERE host_id = 3 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
$stmt_connections_krypton = $conn->query("SELECT connections, epoch_time FROM connections WHERE host_id = 4 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();


prof_flag("Retrieve data");


foreach ($stmt_dbstorage_argon as $row) { $used_space_argon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['used_space']."]";  }
foreach ($stmt_dbstorage_helium as $row) {  $used_space_helium[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['used_space']."]";  }
foreach ($stmt_dbstorage_neon as $row) { $used_space_neon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['used_space']."]"; }  
foreach ($stmt_dbstorage_krypton as $row) { $used_space_krypton[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['used_space']."]";    } 

foreach ($stmt_available_tickets_helium as $row) {
    $read_tickets_helium[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['read_tickets']."]";
    $write_tickets_helium[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['write_tickets']."]";
 }

foreach ($stmt_available_tickets_neon as $row) {
    $read_tickets_neon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['read_tickets']."]";
    $write_tickets_neon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['write_tickets']."]"; 
}

foreach ($stmt_available_tickets_argon as $row) {
    $read_tickets_argon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['read_tickets']."]";
    $write_tickets_argon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['write_tickets']."]"; 
}

foreach ($stmt_available_tickets_krypton as $row) {
    $read_tickets_krypton[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['read_tickets']."]";
    $write_tickets_krypton[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['write_tickets']."]";
 }

foreach ($stmt_connections_helium as $row) {
    $connections_helium[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['connections']."]";
} 



foreach ($stmt_connections_neon as $row) {
    $connections_neon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['connections']."]";
}  



foreach ($stmt_connections_argon as $row) {
    $connections_argon[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['connections']."]";
}   

foreach ($stmt_connections_krypton as $row) {
    $connections_krypton[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['connections']."]";
}

prof_flag("Done");

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);

//execution time of the script
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' secs'; 

prof_print();
?>
```

On top of the script is a function that shows which part is slow. The output of this part:

Total Execution Time: 34.110798120499 secs
Start
0.000032
Connect to DB
0.045901
Perform query
9.475136
Retrieve data
24.588582
Done

And the retrieving data part with my foreach statements take the most time.

Do you have any ideas how I can make it faster?  One query return around 50k - 150k rows.

Thank you!

Comment: So you are fetching ~1000000 rows and wondering why it possibly could be slow?

Comment: make sure index on (host_id, epoch_time) does exist on those tables

Comment: It seams like you are fetching a lot of data. Maybe you could try to use asynchronous request to load it one after the other and then update the frontend  ? This way, your page would load fast, with no data, and the data would come when it's ready. Just an idea here.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code by merging all queries into one by using

```
...WHERE host_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

or using

```
UNION
```

That would minimize all the DB access overhead.

4 x 50k - 150k rows is a lot, do you really need them all at once? Perhaps you can process them with a batch job, cache the results, and access only the cache?

Comment: UNION doesn't optimize anything, especially in terms of returning a huge resultset. The question is not about SQL at all, but specifically about fetching.

Comment: Also all these `$read_tickets_helium = ...` can be done in SQL too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I need the data for monitoring reasons. If I use WHERE host_id IN (1,2,3,4) how can I get the data for host_id = 1; host_id=2,... ?

Comment: @mymarcelsql `SELECT host_id`?

Comment: @mymarcelsql depends on what do you want to do with the data afterward

Comment: @Justinas if I change my queries from where host_id = 1 to where host_id in (1,2,3,4) then it would return the data for every host_id in one dataset. I need to differentiate between the host_ids.

Comment: @EriksKlotins I'm using highcharts and I create charts with a timeline and these values. And I have multiple charts (per host_id) So I need a dataset for host_id = 1, host_id=2 and so on...

Comment: @mymarcelsql in this case you could use the DB to stratify data by hour/day/week/etc thus reducing the total number of rows transferred between the db and your app